# Snippets duplicados Sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

He instalado algunos paquetes en sublime text 3, paquetes como: latextools, latexing, latex-plus ... entre otros.

Cada uno de los paquetes tiene cierta ventaja, pero tengo el siguiente problema: más de un snippet se repite.

Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una solución que se me ocurrió fue, la de entrar al mismo directorio de cada paquete y editar el **tabTrigger** de cada snippet (me resultó), otra solución fue la de borrar, copiar o mover algunos snippets dentro de directorio user, también me resultó con algunos.

Pero hay algunos snippets que no logro encontrarlos. Incluso los busque con la función Ctrl + Shit + F, pero nada.

Entonces mi pregunta es:

- **Existe alguna forma para administrar los snippets duplicados?**

Answer (score 1):

Luego de revisar en la red, encontré la solución a mi problema, el cual comparto. 
Existe un paquete llamado: [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) el cual instalé y realicé los siguientes pasos:

```
Ctrl+Shift+P
```

donde se busca **Package Resource Viewer > Open Resource**, en mi caso particular busque **LaTeX**, y dentro de **Snippets**, en el cual me lista todos los snippet que viene por defecto al instalar sublime (el cual según tengo entendido no es posible acceder), luego busque el snippet que me genera problemas, por ejemplo section-..-(section).sublime-snippet y lo abro y edito y lo guardo Packages/LaTeX/section-..-(section).sublime-snippet, esto, ya sea con el mismo o distinto tabtigger y listo ya no se repite.

bueno con esto solucione mi problema, de seguro que se puede aplicar a otros lenguajes.